# Does "reclaim" make sense in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I reclaimed serenity and readjusted myself to this new life.

We can reclaim a property from someone else, but can we reclaim serenity from the angry self which was already the past existence of me?

Comment: I have this sense that there's another, better word I can't quite think of, but "reclaimed" seems fine in the above context.

Comment: I think regardless of whether you end up using *reclaim* or *recover* (or some other word) as your initial verb, you should add "my" before serenity, as in typical English usage you would declare whose serenity is being recovered.  Without the "my", the sentence sounds stilted and odd, as though one were reclaiming an abstract notion rather than your own personal sense of serenity.

Answer (score 3):

Did you once have serenity?

Did something (or someone) lead you to lose it?

Did you take steps to once again have that serenity?

Then you reclaimed it.

It's a figurative use, not a literal one, but the nuances come from the nuances of the literal meaning; to *claim* is to demand more than it is to request, and so it only works figuratively if you insisted on this new state or took active steps to ensure it.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer. But I was also interested in your notion of claim indicating insistence. It has become fashionable for football commentators to use it, as in *The goalkeeper rose high above the other players to claim the ball*. And I guess that is what a goalkeeper is supposed to do, isn't it!

Comment: @WS2 I think my consistently failing to insist upon anything on the pitch is one of the reasons I was never very good at sports.

Comment: In my example, recover and reclaim, which one is better?

Comment: *Recover* is the one that is more literally correct (though it was originally a figurative use too), but *reclaim* could be all the better for precisely that reason. Or it could be too strong, depending on just what you mean. As such I would say that it's either completely wrong (because it implies more active an act than was the case) or else it's the better word. There is an element of taste in such things, of course.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I would also add that "reclaim" implies a more *triumphant* attitude, as in having defeated the person or situation which had taken your serenity from you; while "recover" implies a somewhat more solitary, quiet, even slightly sheepish attitude, as you have merely found what you yourself lost earlier.

Answer (score 0):

"Reclaim" makes sense to me in this context.

I take this figurative use of (re)claim to mean "assert (re)acquisition/(re)take possession" of something. I've seen "reclaim" used similarly in the phrase "reclaimed the lead." This usage can be found in [sports](http://www.nba.com/pacers/rewind-pacers-bulls-141229), [business/politics](http://tidescanada.org/2012/04/bloomberg2011rankings/), and [other contexts](http://headlineplanet.com/home/2014/12/22/taylor-swifts-1989-reclaims-lead-itunes-album-sales-chart/). The phrase "reclaimed his/her health" also appears to be fairly common.

And I agree with Jon Hanna that "recover" also fits here to mean that the person lost something abstract (serenity) and now has it again, with "reclaim" adding a sense of the person *asserting* that he/she is once again serene.